Is it possible to create a type that includes a certain property if there is another one in typescript
At work, I was making a react component that can accept additional parameters, but I wanted to make the ide swear that if it didn't pass a flag or some other prop
This led me to the next task
type ItemBase = {
    title: string
    //any other fields
}

type ItemFlagged = {
    flag: true
    additionField: string
}

type ItemNonFlagged = {
    // empty object type
}

type ItemOptions = ItemFlagged | ItemNonFlagged

type Item = any //???

const a: Item = {
    title: 'some'
}

const b: Item = {
    title: 'some',
    flag: true,
    additionField: 'test'
}

// @ts-expect-error
const c: Item = {
    title: 'c',
    additionField: 'call'
}

Can you tell me if it is possible to make such a type, if so, then show how, and if not, what causes it
Thank you in advance

It's not at all clear to me what you're going for. The Item type is any and will allow, well, any type of property. Should Item be ItemBase and either ItemFlagged or not?

Does this approach meet your needs? If so I'll write an answer or find a suitable duplication source; if not, what am I missing?
